# bit cast uint64_t to double and back in a macro

Tags: c, performance, macros

```
union uint64_t_double {
    uint64_t u;
    double d;
};

uint64_t double_to_uint64_t(double d) {
    union uint64_t_double ud;
    ud.d = d;
    return ud.u;
}

double uint64_t_to_double(int64_t u) {
    union uint64_t_double ud;
    ud.u = u;
    return ud.d;
}
```

Basically, can I convert these two functions to macros?

I need this becaus TinyC does not optimize(inline) functions calls as clang/gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define ReinterpretDoubleAsUint64_t(x) ((union { double d; uint64_t u; }) { x } .u)

#define ReinterpretUint64_tAsDouble(x) ((union { uint64_t u; double d; }) { x } .d)
```

In C, code “(*type*) { *initializer-list* }” is a *compound literal*. It creates an object with the specified type and initialization. So:

```
(union { double d; uint64_t u; }) { x }
```

creates a union that is initialized with `x`. By default, the first member of the union is initialized, so this is a union in which the `double` member `d` has been set to `x`. Give that union, `.u` is simply the usual way of referring to a member of a union. So:

```
(union { double d; uint64_t u; }) { x } .u
```

is the member `u` of the union. When a union member other than the last one stored is read, the bytes of the union are reinterpreted in new type. So this reinterprets the bytes of the `double` as `uint64_t`.

This is standard C, but it uses implementation-defined behavior (notably, the way `double` values are encoded depends on the implementation, as does whether `double` and `uint64_t` have the same size).

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this definition ? I don't understand the declaration inside the parentheses.

Comment: In my tests this approach is only 10% slower(tcc) than pointer conversion, but it works with literals.

Comment: @KarimManaouil: Done.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is very interesting. Thanks.